# SQL DB2 Split result of group by based on count

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to split the result of a group by in several rows based on a count, but I don't know if it's possible. For instance, if I have a query like this :

```
SELECT doc.client, doc.template, COUNT(doc) FROM document doc GROUP BY doc.client, doc.template
```

and a table document with the following data :

```
ID | name  | client | template
1  | doc_a | a      | temp_a
2  | doc_b | a      | temp_a
3  | doc_c | a      | temp_a
4  | doc_d | a      | temp_b
```

The result for the query would be :

```
client | template | count
a      | temp_a   | 3
a      | temp_b   | 1
```

But I would like to split a row of the result in two or more if the count is higher than 2 :

```
client | template | count
a      | temp_a   | 2
a      | temp_a   | 1
a      | temp_b   | 1
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RCTE like below. Run this statement **AS IS** first playing with different values in the last column. Max batch size here is 1000.

```
WITH 
  GRP_RESULT (client, template, count) AS
(
-- Place your SELECT ... GROUP BY here
-- instead of VALUES 
VALUES
  ('a', 'temp_a', 4500)
, ('a', 'temp_b', 3001)
)
, T (client, template, count, max_batch_size) AS 
(
SELECT client, template, count, 1000
FROM GRP_RESULT
  UNION ALL
SELECT client, template, count - max_batch_size, max_batch_size
FROM T
WHERE count > max_batch_size
)
SELECT client, template, CASE WHEN count > max_batch_size THEN max_batch_size ELSE count END count
FROM T
ORDER BY client, template, count DESC
```

The result is:

```
|CLIENT|TEMPLATE|COUNT      |
|------|--------|-----------|
|a     |temp_a  |1000       |
|a     |temp_a  |1000       |
|a     |temp_a  |1000       |
|a     |temp_a  |1000       |
|a     |temp_a  |500        |
|a     |temp_b  |1000       |
|a     |temp_b  |1000       |
|a     |temp_b  |1000       |
|a     |temp_b  |1          |
```

You may place your `SELECT ... GROUP BY` statement as specified above afterwards to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and then aggregate:

```
SELECT client, template, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT doc.client, doc.template,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc.client, doc.template ORDER BY doc.client) - 1 as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY doc.client, doc.template) as cnt
      FROM document doc
     ) d
GROUP BY doc.client, doc.template, floor(seqnum * n / cnt)
```

The subquery enumerates the rows.  The outer query then splits the rows into groups of two using `MOD()`.

Comment: Thank you ! Would it also split in three, four, five, ... ? If for instance I have a result with a count of 20, I would then need it divided into 10 rows

Comment: @Minemosynne . . . Yes, you would change the `2` to whatever maximum size you want.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my post when explaining my issue (I've corrected the post). I cannot have a count number higher than a certain number, and if the count is higher than that number, it should be split in several rows. So for instance, let's say the max number for the count is 5, if I have a count of 7, I would like to have 2 rows (5 and 2). A count of 20 would make 4 rows (5, 5, 5, and 5), etc.

Comment: @Minemosynne . . . That is what this answer does.

Comment: When I tried it, with a count of 89, instead of having 45 rows returned with counts of 2 and 1 for the last one, I have 2 rows with a count of 45 and 44 each

Comment: @Minemosynne . . . Duh.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: It does the same thing as the one before, the number I put end up being the numbers of rows I receive. But I don't know the numbers of rows beforehand, I just know the maximum count I can have. It's to make batches of documents to process. And a batch (a row) can't have more documents than a 1000. If the batch has 1100 documents, I want 2 batches of 1000 and 100 documents. If a batch has 4500 documents, I want 5 batches (4 batches of 1000 documents, and one of 500 documents). But thank you for your time, I'll try and search something else.